# Как корректно добавить алиасы в конфигурацию линтера?

Tags: typescript, eslint, alias

Всем добрый день.

React + TS

Есть файл с алиасами (config-overrides.js)

```
 const {
  addWebpackAlias,
  override,
} = require('customize-cra');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = override(addWebpackAlias({
  '@ui': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/ui'),
  '@features': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/features'),
}));
```

И есть установленный линтер, он ругается на импорты, мне необходимо чтобы он не ругался, при этом нельзя добавлять исключения, задача стоит указать алиасы в линтере.

Вот файл eslintrc.js -

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 0,
    'react/display-name': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/indent': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 0,
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': 0,
    'react/jsx-fragments': 0,
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 0,
    'comma-dangle': 0,
    'operator-linebreak': 0,
    'import/no-dynamic-require': 0,
    'implicit-arrow-linebreak': 0,
    'react/jsx-curly-brace-presence': 0,
    'no-multiple-empty-lines': 0,
    'func-names': 0,
    'no-trailing-spaces': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': [
      2,
      {
        argsIgnorePattern: '^_',
      },
    ],
    'no-console': [
      2,
      {
        allow: ['info', 'warn', 'error'],
      },
    ],
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [
          ['@ui', './src/ui'],
          ['@features/', './src/features']
        ],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx']
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Пакеты которые установлены для eslint:
"eslint": "^7.12.1",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
"eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",

В текущем виде после прогона линтером выводится много ошибок в виде - import/prefer-default-export или import/no-unresolved

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно добавить алиасы в конфигурацию линтера, или возможно где почитать похожий случай чтобы разобраться.

Спасибо большое.